# Commutable operators and eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator, eigenvalue

My lecture notes says Since $[\hat{L^2} ,\hat{L_{z}}] = 0$
Then $Y(\theta,\phi)$ solves the below equations simultaneously:

$$\hat{L^2}Y(\theta,\phi) = A Y(\theta,\phi)$$

$$\hat{L_{z}}Y(\theta,\phi) = B Y(\theta,\phi)$$

I take this to mean, given $Y$ is an eigenfunction of one operator, it is also an eigenfunction of the other operator.

**Is this strictly true? I am having some doubt since:**

By virtue of being eigenfunctions of the two operators it follows that for $Y$,
$$\Delta  \hat{L^2} = 0$$
$$\Delta  \hat{L_{z}} = 0$$

However the only condition that we obtain from the commutability of these two operators is:
$$\Delta  \hat{L^2} \Delta  \hat{L_{z}} \geq \frac{1}{2i} \langle[\hat{L^2} ,\hat{L_{z}}]\rangle $$

$$\Delta  \hat{L^2} \Delta  \hat{L_{z}} \geq 0$$

Does this imply commutability shows Y being an eigenfunction of one operator means it is an eigenfunction of the other, as my lecture notes say

Since we could theoretically have
$$\Delta  \hat{L^2} = 0$$
$$\Delta  \hat{L_{z}} ≠ 0$$

Which still satisfies the commutability of the two operators, yet for this example $Y$ would not be an eigenfunction of $\hat{L_{z}}$ since it is implied by the eigenfunction equation that $\Delta  \hat{L_{z}} = 0$

Comment: Your question seems very confused to me. If two hermitian operators commute, they share a common (orthonormal) eigenbasis. Additionally, if one of these operators has a non-degenerate eigenstate, then this is also an eigenstate of the other operator. Does that help?

Comment: Commutativity implies stability of eigenspaces under each other's action, however since the eigenspaces might not be one dimensional this does not mean that every eigenvector of one must be mapped by the other onto a multiple of itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My lecture notes says Since $[\hat{L^2} ,\hat{L_{z}}] = 0$
> Then $Y(\theta,\phi)$ solves the below equations simultaneously:
>
> $$\hat{L^2}Y(\theta,\phi) = A Y(\theta,\phi)$$
>
> $$\hat{L_{z}}Y(\theta,\phi) = B Y(\theta,\phi)$$
>
> I take this to mean, given $Y$ is an eigenfunction of one operator, it is also an eigenfunction of the other operator.

Not necessarily. An eigenfunction of one operator is not *guaranteed* to be an eigenfunction of the other operator.

When two operators commute, you **can find** functions that are simultaneous eigenfunctions of both. But it doesn't mean that any old function that happens to be an eigenfunction of one will necessarily be an eigenfunction of the other.

---

For example, the function $\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\sim Y_{1,1}+Y_{1,-1}$ is an eigenfunction of $L^2$, but not of $L_z$.

But you can choose functions $Y_{1,1}$, $Y_{1,0}$, and $Y_{1,-1}$ that are simultaneous eigenfunctions of both $L^2$ and $L_z$.